# How to permanently embed images in an ioslides presentation?

Tags: image, r-markdown, knitr, ioslides

I'm having trouble permanently embedding images in my RStudio ioslides presentation.

Specifically, the problem occurs when I try to include local images via:

```
![](image.png)
```

The images will appear successfully when I knit the document and open it directly from its folder on my computer. But if I share the html file with anyone else or copy and paste to another directory on my computer, all images embedded via `![](image.png)` disappear.

My YAML header looks like this:

```
---
title: 'Title'
subtitle: 'Subtitle'
author: "Harrison"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    self_contained: true
    widescreen: true
    smaller: true
    css: custom.css
    incremental: false
---
```

I thought that "self-contained" is supposed to accomplish what I want, that is, to create a fully self-contained html document.

Note: My images **are** successfully permanently embedded when I use the `include_graphics()` function from knitr to add a jpeg or png file.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: include_graphics is probably converting them to base64 so the image information is embeded on the text.

Comment: is there a way I can do the same to convert the images produced by `![](image.png)` to base64?

Comment: Sure, but you have to make sure thats what include_graphics is doing. You need to see its output. If is a long string of characters and numbers is probably base64 and you can then use https://www.base64-image.de/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is my reproducible example:

````
---
title: 'Title'
subtitle: 'Subtitle'
author: "Harrison"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    self_contained: true
    keep_md: true
---

## First slide

```{r, test, dev='png'}
plot(1)
```

## Second slide

![](`r knitr::fig_chunk('test', 'png')`)
````

Both images are corrected embedded.

Please try to [update your packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/). If it still fails after updating all packages, please provide your `xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')`.